# Forking Multiple Times

Tags: c

So this is a snippet of my code:

```
pid_t children[MAX_PIPES];
for (i = 0; i < numPipes; i++)
{
    pid_t child_pid = fork();
    children[i] = child_pid;

    switch(child_pid)
    {
        case 0:
            // Some code thats executed in the child that executes execv()
            break;
        case -1: // Unable to create child
            perror("fork");
            break;
    }
}
// Wait for children 
for (j = 0; j < numPipes && children[j] != 0; j++)
{
    if (background)
        waitpid(children[j], &status, WNOHANG);
    else
        waitpid(children[j], &status, 0);
}
```

Currently it works fine when I only call execv() once, but I am trying to execute multiple commands using execv() one after the other inside the already forked child process.

How do I go about adding that functionality? I have tried to add another fork() inside a loop inside the child but it wasnt successful.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You could review the code in [What is the proper way to pipe when making a shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673333/) or [Pipe stream and child processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845060/) or [Pipe communication in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192956/) or [Multiple processes and pipes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190352/) or no doubt many others; those are simply a few of the ones I've seen in the past couple of months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems is that `execv` replaces the entire child process with the command being called, so you can't put more than one execv command into the child process.

If you want to have multiple commands, you have to `fork()`, `execv()` each one. You're could use `system()`, but it doesn't process parameters in the same manner as `execv()` (it launches a shell).

If you want to run multiple commands, then you should do a second `fork()` ... `execv()` using a wrapper akin to:

```
int
subv(char *path, char * const argv[])
{
  int ret;
  pid_t a_pid = fork();
  if (a_pid == -1) return -1;
  if (a_pid != 0) { wait(&ret); return ret; }
  return execv(path, argv);
}
```

The you replace all the execv calls with subv() and deal with the return code appropriately.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is wrong.  Your `subv()` command does not return in the parent until the child has completed, but you can't rely on the processes in a pipeline completing before the next process is started.  In general, the first process in the pipeline will generate too much data for the pipe, and will block waiting for the second process to read the data from the pipe, but with this code, the second process won't be started, so you'll have a deadlock.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In this case, he does not look to be using pipes to process input/output which is why I proposed this simple solution.

Comment: Hmmm...`i < numPipes` might be taken to indicate otherwise, though I grant you there is no sign of the `pipe()` call or any of the `close()` calls that would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`execv`, like the other `exec()` commands, doesn't return except on failure.  The context for the new program is loaded in place of the current program.